# mysql_fetch_array by date php

Tags: mysql, arrays, date

I have a list of fixtures in a table in my database. They have the following columns:

```
hometeam, awayteam, date, time
```

At the moment I used fetch array to write out a big table:

```
Fulham v Aston Villa | 13/08/2011 | 15:00
West Bromwich Albion v Manchester United | 13/08/2011 | 15:00
Liverpool v Sunderland | 13/08/2011 | 15:00
```

etc etc

What I wanted to do is have it slightly different:

```
13/08/2011 | 15:00
Fulham v Aston Villa
West Bromwich Albion v Manchester United
Liverpool v Sunderland

20/08/2011 | 15:00
Arsenal v Liverpool
Bolton v Manchester City
etc etc
```

can someone help me to understand the best way to do this please?

Answer (score 0):

Sort your data by date (add `ORDER BY DATE` to the query) and then just display. Keep track of when the date changes so that you only need to print the date when it changes.

Answer (score 0):

You want to group the teams by date. You'll want to use `GROUP BY date, time`. This will order all the teams using the date.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for a query like this:

```
SELECT date, time, GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT(hometeam, ' v ', awayteam) ORDER BY hometeam, awayteam
    SEPARATOR '\n'
  ) AS fix
FROM fixture
GROUP BY date, time
ORDER BY date DESC;
```